# How to reset database migrations using EF code first?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a class library project with my DbContext and migration enabled with following config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext" connectionString="Data Source=Data.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Some time before I played with migrations for this project and Get-Migrations command always returns following to me:

```
PM> Get-Migrations -StartupProjectName "Data"
Retrieving migrations that have been applied to the target database.
201207012104355_Initial
201207012031234_Initial
201207012024250_Initial
```

The problem is that command always returns these items even if I delete Data.sdf or delete all project and make new one. The only way I can create new database is changing database file name in connection string from Data.sdf to Data1.sdf for example.
So how can i reset migration history without changing database name?

Comment: Are you sure that you have deleted a correct Data.sdf file?

Comment: Seems I needed to delete Data.sdf there:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Data.sdf
Very unexpected.

Comment: Migrations create a table in your database called __MigrationHistory, it's where the migrations are stored. Have you checked it?

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if this is the official method.  But here's how I did it.

1. Deleted migration file
2. Deleted matching row from __MigrationHistory

   DELETE FROM __MigrationHistory WHERE MigrationId='201210271944168_AddLogTable'